How do I destroy frames and make it appear the way it was before in tkinter?

In the code below, I'm destroying frame1 and frame2, so that the messages can make use of the extra space after destroying frame1 and frame2.
The functionality I need is:
When a message is sent, frame1 and frame2 must get destroyed automatically.
The messages must make use of the extra space but the messages must be below new_note_button.
When new_note_button is clicked, I want all messages to be cleared and frame1, frame2 to appear how it was before.
I tried to recreate frame1 and frame2 when new_note_button is clicked but the frames are in different places and multiple frames are getting created (check the image I've attached).
Here's my code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

frames_loaded = True

def clear_chat_log():
    global frames_loaded
    if not frames_loaded:
        # Create frames to group the boxes
        frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
        frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=(0, 40), pady=(100, 1))

        frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
        frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=(0, 40), pady=(5, 20))

        style.configure("PDF.TButton", font=('Sans-serif', 12,), background="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray", borderwidth=1)
        chat_with_pdf_button = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Teyxxxxxxxxxxxx", style="PDF.TButton")
        chat_with_pdf_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, ipadx=(135), padx=(0, 10), ipady=14)

        option2_label = tk.Label(frame1, text="testxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", font=('Sans-serif', 12,), bg="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray", padx=95, pady=20)
        option2_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        # Create labels for the options in the second frame
        option3_label = tk.Label(frame2, text="testzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", font=('Sans-serif', 12,), bg="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray", padx=116, pady=20)
        option3_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(0, 10))

        option4_label = tk.Label(frame2, text="testqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq", font=('Sans-serif', 12,), bg="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray", padx=115, pady=20)
        option4_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        frames_loaded = True
        return

root = tk.Tk()
# Adjust the placement of other widgets accordingly
root.title("Test")
# Maximize the window
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("clam")
chat_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
chat_frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

chat_log = tk.Text(chat_frame, state='disabled', wrap='word', width=70, height=15, font=('Sans-serif', 12), bg="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
chat_log.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(500,0), pady=10, expand = True, fill = tk.BOTH)

# Create frames to group the boxes
frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=(0, 40), pady=(100, 1))

frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=(0, 40), pady=(5, 20))

style.configure("PDF.TButton", font=('Sans-serif', 12,), background="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray", borderwidth=1)
chat_with_pdf_button = ttk.Button(frame1, text="Teyxxxxxxxxxxxx", style="PDF.TButton")
chat_with_pdf_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, ipadx=(135), padx=(0, 10), ipady=14)

option2_label = tk.Label(frame1, text="testxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", font=('Sans-serif', 12,), bg="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray", padx=95, pady=20)
option2_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

# Create labels for the options in the second frame
option3_label = tk.Label(frame2, text="testzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", font=('Sans-serif', 12,), bg="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray", padx=116, pady=20)
option3_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(0, 10))

option4_label = tk.Label(frame2, text="testqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq", font=('Sans-serif', 12,), bg="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray", padx=115, pady=20)
option4_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

def append_to_chat_log(sender=None, message=None):
  
    chat_log.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
    if sender:
        chat_log.insert("end", f"{sender}\n\n", "sender")
        
        #chat_log.insert("end",'\n\n')
    if message:
        chat_log.insert("end", message)
    chat_log.tag_config("sender", font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), foreground="black")
    chat_log.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
    chat_log.see("end")
    chat_log.update()

def send_message(event=None):
    global frames_loaded
    if frame1:
        frame1.destroy()
    if frame2:
        frame2.destroy()
    frames_loaded = False
    message = message_entry.get(1.0, "end-1c") 
    message = message.strip()
    message_entry.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    message_entry.update()
    
    if not message:
        pass 
    else:
        canvas1.place(x=495,y=80)
        canvas1.update()
        
        append_to_chat_log("User")
        append_to_chat_log(message=message)
        append_to_chat_log(message="\n")
        canvas1.place_forget()
        canvas1.update()

new_note_button = ttk.Button(chat_frame, style="Toggle.TButton", text=" New Note", compound="left", command=clear_chat_log)
new_note_button.place(x=490,y=40)

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=250, height=70, bg="white", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
# Display "Loading" text
loading_text = canvas1.create_text(70, 50, text="Loading...", anchor="e")

message_entry = tk.Text(root, padx=17, insertbackground='white', bg="white", fg="black", width=70, height=1, spacing1=20, spacing3=20, font=('Open Sans', 14))
message_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(500, 0), pady=(0, 70))  # Adjust pady to move it slightly above the bottom
#message_entry.insert(0, "Ask me anything...")
message_entry.insert(1.0, "Type")
message_entry.mark_set("insert", "%d.%d" % (0,0))
message_entry.bind("<Return>", send_message)
root.mainloop()


I took the liberty of turning your code into an object-oriented approach. Instead of deleting the two frames, you can simply unpack them with pack_forget(). This way you don't have to recreate them, but can simply call pack() again with the appropriate parameters.
For the placement of the button in the chat I did not use the place but the grid() manager and configured it with weight on the rows so that the second row with the chat expands accordingly.
As a little goodie, I have written you a small class that provides the text widget with a placeholder.
Here is your adapted code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class EntryWithPlaceholder(tk.Text):
    """Entry with placeholder so user does not accidentally send 'Type'"""
    def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="PLACEHOLDER", color='grey', *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.placeholder_color = color
        self.default_fg_color = self['fg']

        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.foc_in)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.foc_out)

        self.put_placeholder()

    def put_placeholder(self):
        self.insert('1.0', self.placeholder)
        self['fg'] = self.placeholder_color

    def foc_in(self, *args):
        if self['fg'] == self.placeholder_color:
            self.delete('1.0', 'end')
            self['fg'] = self.default_fg_color

    def foc_out(self, *args):
        if len(self.get('1.0', 'end')) <= 1:
            self.put_placeholder()


class Chat(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # instead of "root = tk.Tk()" → root is now self
        # overall GUI settings
        self.title("Test")
        # Maximize the window
        self.state('zoomed')  # changed from root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use("clam")
        # declare own style "PDF.TButton"
        self.style.configure("PDF.TButton", font=('Sans-serif', 12,), background="white", fg="black",
                             highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray", borderwidth=1)
        # global variables as instance variables to make them accessible inside the class methods
        self.frames_loaded = True
        # create widget frames
        self._create_chat_frame()
        self._create_frame1()
        self._create_frame2()
        # create widgets in root
        self.canvas1 = tk.Canvas(self, width=250, height=70, bg="white", borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        # Display "Loading" text
        loading_text = self.canvas1.create_text(70, 50, text="Loading...", anchor="e")
        # own Entry class with placeholder
        self.message_entry = EntryWithPlaceholder(self, padx=17, insertbackground='white', bg="white", fg="black",
                                                  width=70, height=1, spacing1=20, spacing3=20, font=('Open Sans', 14),
                                                  placeholder='Type...')
        # Adjust pady to move it slightly above the bottom
        self.message_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(500, 0), pady=(0, 70))
        # Binding of entry → placeholder is set in instantiation
        self.message_entry.bind("<Return>", self.send_message)

    def _create_chat_frame(self):
        self.chat_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="white")
        self.chat_frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        # set weights to expand the row with the chat
        self.chat_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.chat_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        new_note_button = ttk.Button(self.chat_frame, style="Toggle.TButton", text=" New Note", compound="left",
                                     command=self.clear_chat_log)
        new_note_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W', padx=490, pady=40)

        self.chat_log = tk.Text(self.chat_frame, state='disabled', wrap='word', width=70, height=15,
                                font=('Sans-serif', 12), bg="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
        self.chat_log.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NESW', padx=(500, 0), pady=10)

    def _create_frame1(self):
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self, bg="white")
        self.frame1.pack(padx=(0, 40), pady=(100, 1))

        self.chat_with_pdf_button = ttk.Button(self.frame1, text="Teyxxxxxxxxxxxx", style="PDF.TButton")
        self.chat_with_pdf_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, ipadx=135, padx=(0, 10), ipady=14)

        self.option2_label = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="testxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", font=('Sans-serif', 12,), bg="white",
                                      fg="black", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray", padx=95, pady=20)
        self.option2_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def _create_frame2(self):
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self, bg="white")
        self.frame2.pack(padx=(0, 40), pady=(5, 20))

        self.option3_label = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="testzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", font=('Sans-serif', 12,),
                                      bg="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray",
                                      padx=116, pady=20)
        self.option3_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(0, 10))

        self.option4_label = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="testqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq", font=('Sans-serif', 12,),
                                      bg="white", fg="black", highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="gray",
                                      padx=115, pady=20)
        self.option4_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    def clear_chat_log(self):
        if not self.frames_loaded:
            # you have to restore the order, so first forget the entry text widget
            self.message_entry.pack_forget()
            # then just pack the parent frames again
            self.frame1.pack(padx=(0, 40), pady=(100, 1))
            self.frame2.pack(padx=(0, 40), pady=(5, 20))
            # and then the message entry again
            self.message_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(500, 0), pady=(0, 70))
            self.frames_loaded = True

    def append_to_chat_log(self, sender=None, message=None):
        self.chat_log.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        if sender:
            self.chat_log.insert("end", f"{sender}\n\n", "sender")

            # chat_log.insert("end",'\n\n')
        if message:
            self.chat_log.insert("end", message)
        self.chat_log.tag_config("sender", font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'), foreground="black")
        self.chat_log.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.chat_log.see("end")
        self.chat_log.update()

    def send_message(self, event=None):
        if self.frames_loaded:
            # just pack_forget() the frames, no need to destroy if you want to reuse them
            self.frame1.pack_forget()
            self.frame2.pack_forget()
            self.frames_loaded = False

        message = self.message_entry.get(1.0, "end-1c")
        message = message.strip()
        self.message_entry.delete('1.0', 'end')
        self.message_entry.update()

        if not message:
            pass
        else:
            self.canvas1.place(x=495, y=80)
            self.canvas1.update()

            self.append_to_chat_log("User")
            self.append_to_chat_log(message=message)
            self.append_to_chat_log(message="\n")
            self.canvas1.place_forget()
            self.canvas1.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Chat()
    app.mainloop()


